# Access violation when assigning a value to an element of a map vector container

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary

I defined a template class as follows:

```
template <class T, size_t IR_CAL_LEVELS> 
class CCalibrationTable
{
public:
// Default Constructor/Destructor
    CCalibrationTable(void);
    ~CCalibrationTable(void) {}

// Implementation
    void Decode(const unsigned char* pszData);

protected:
    int  m_nActiveSensorID;                                        // Sensor selection 1-primary sensor, 2-backup sensor (11) I*1
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<T> > m_mapCalibrationTables; // Calibration tables such as VIS 64-level albedo cnversion table, and 
                                                                   // IR Level-temperature conversion tables.
private:
    static const size_t VIS_CAL_LEVELS;
    static const size_t NUM_OF_GROUPS;
};

template<class T, size_t IR_CAL_LEVELS> 
const size_t CCalibrationTable<T, IR_CAL_LEVELS>::VIS_CAL_LEVELS = 64;

template<class T, size_t IR_CAL_LEVELS> 
const size_t CCalibrationTable<T, IR_CAL_LEVELS>::NUM_OF_GROUPS = 25;

template<class T, size_t IR_CAL_LEVELS> 
CCalibrationTable<T, IR_CAL_LEVELS>::CCalibrationTable() 
{   
    // For VIS channels
    m_mapCalibrationTables.insert(std::make_pair("VIS1Cal", std::vector<T>(VIS_CAL_LEVELS, 0)));
    m_mapCalibrationTables.insert(std::make_pair("VIS2Cal", std::vector<T>(VIS_CAL_LEVELS, 0)));
    m_mapCalibrationTables.insert(std::make_pair("VIS3Cal", std::vector<T>(VIS_CAL_LEVELS, 0)));
    m_mapCalibrationTables.insert(std::make_pair("VIS4Cal", std::vector<T>(VIS_CAL_LEVELS, 0)));

    // For IR channels
    m_mapCalibrationTables.insert(std::make_pair("IR1Cal", std::vector<T>(IR_CAL_LEVELS, 0)));
    m_mapCalibrationTables.insert(std::make_pair("IR2Cal", std::vector<T>(IR_CAL_LEVELS, 0)));
    m_mapCalibrationTables.insert(std::make_pair("IR3Cal", std::vector<T>(IR_CAL_LEVELS, 0)));
    m_mapCalibrationTables.insert(std::make_pair("IR4Cal", std::vector<T>(IR_CAL_LEVELS, 0)));
}    

template<class T, size_t IR_CAL_LEVELS> 
void CCalibrationTable<T, IR_CAL_LEVELS>::Decode(const unsigned char* pszData)
{   
    // Sensor selection 1-primary sensor, 2-backup sensor (11) I*1 
    m_nActiveSensorID = CBCDDecoder::SINTn(1, &(pszData[CBCDDecoder::IndexI2D(11)]));

    for (size_t nVISLevel = 0; nVISLevel < VIS_CAL_LEVELS; nVISLevel++) 
    {   
        int nOffset = (nVISLevel << 2);

        m_mapCalibrationTables["VIS1Cal"][nVISLevel] = CBCDDecoder::REALnm(4, 6, &(pszData[CBCDDecoder::IndexI2D(257                             + nOffset)]));
        m_mapCalibrationTables["VIS2Cal"][nVISLevel] = CBCDDecoder::REALnm(4, 6, &(pszData[CBCDDecoder::IndexI2D(257 + (VIS_CAL_LEVELS << 2)     + nOffset)]));
        m_mapCalibrationTables["VIS3Cal"][nVISLevel] = CBCDDecoder::REALnm(4, 6, &(pszData[CBCDDecoder::IndexI2D(257 + (VIS_CAL_LEVELS << 2) * 2 + nOffset)]));
        m_mapCalibrationTables["VIS4Cal"][nVISLevel] = CBCDDecoder::REALnm(4, 6, &(pszData[CBCDDecoder::IndexI2D(257 + (VIS_CAL_LEVELS << 2) * 3 + nOffset)]));
    }

    for (int nIRLevel = 0; nIRLevel < IR_CAL_LEVELS; nIRLevel++)
    {   
        int nOffset = (nIRLevel << 2);

        m_mapCalibrationTables["IR1Cal"][nIRLevel] = CBCDDecoder::REALnm(4, 3, &(pszData[CBCDDecoder::IndexI2D(1281                            + nOffset)]));
        m_mapCalibrationTables["IR2Cal"][nIRLevel] = CBCDDecoder::REALnm(4, 3, &(pszData[CBCDDecoder::IndexI2D(1281 + (IR_CAL_LEVELS << 2)     + nOffset)]));
        m_mapCalibrationTables["IR3Cal"][nIRLevel] = CBCDDecoder::REALnm(4, 3, &(pszData[CBCDDecoder::IndexI2D(1281 + (IR_CAL_LEVELS << 2) * 2 + nOffset)]));
        m_mapCalibrationTables["IR4Cal"][nIRLevel] = CBCDDecoder::REALnm(4, 3, &(pszData[CBCDDecoder::IndexI2D(1281 + (IR_CAL_LEVELS << 2) * 3 + nOffset)]));
    }
}
```

When I use this kind of templated class in another class by firstly declaring like the following:

```
CCalibrationTable<double, 1024> m_CalibrationTable;
```

an error (Access violation reading location 0x00000004) occurred when decoded value was assigned to my map vector container m_mapCalibrationTables. As you see in its constructor, all map keys as well as their respective vector values are ready (preserved space and initialized to 0).

What's wrong with my assignment statement like "m_mapCalibrationTables["VIS1Cal"][nVISLevel] = XXXXX"? You'd better not doubt the return value of my decoders such as REALnm and IndexI2D, which are just return double and integer values respectively. I checked these return values, and they are correct.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this code minimal? (Somehow I doubt it.)

Comment: Who erase my map vector container? I've already initialized in the constructor. But when I used m_CalibrationTable in the Decode function, it was an empty container. Why?

Comment: @Beta 2: Thank you for your attention for my question. Sorry for my late response because it's lunch time for me. "Is this code minimal?" What do you mean? Could you give me detailed explanation?

Comment: By minimal he mean as little amount of code as possible to still reproduce the problem. Try to remove all unnecessary members/methods and mark line in which program fails.

Comment: Also I'm 99% sure that it's not vector or map which is failing, but rather pszData[(...)]. Try to verify that.

Comment: Often the act of paring away irrelevant code makes the bug obvious. It also forms good habits of code simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If I comment out

```
m_nActiveSensorID = CBCDDecoder::SINTn(1, &(pszData[CBCDDecoder::IndexI2D(11)]));
```

and change all calls to CBCDDecoder::REALnm to a constant "0." the code runs fine when compiled with MSVC 2010.
I guess you have some side effect in either your CBCDDecoder functions or anywhere else in the code that is running between the ctor and the Decode.